# How to run weighted panel regression with PLM packege in R

Tags: r, panel, plm

I want to run a panel regression in R with the help of plm. Its basic function has a parameter weights, but I cannot understand in what way and format I have to put it there. Can any one help

Consider a toy example.

```
Y <- c(1, 8, 3, 6, 3, 1, 9, 9, 7)
X <- c(2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2)
Z <- c(6, 2, 3, 4, 10, 4, 5, 10, 2)
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)

a <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y, X, Z, ID)) # combine to get df
a <- pdata.frame(a, index = c("ID")) # convert to panel df
head(a)
```

I want my regressors to have the following weights:

```
w <- c(1, 2, 0.3)
```

When I run regression I receive an error about diffferent lengths. I have no idea, how I should give weights

```
p_model <- plm(formula = Y ~ X + Z, data = a, model = "within", weights = w)
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Reading the plm documentation was not helpful

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer: simple repeat the weights

```
w <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
```